# how to search product with elasticsearch

Tags: search, elasticsearch

This is my DSL:

```
{
  "query": {
    "function_score": {
      "query": {
        "multi_match": {
          "query":    "testa",
          "analyzer":"standard",
          "type": "best_fields",
          "fields": [ "name^5", "content^1" ]
        }
      },
      "field_value_factor": {
        "field":    "popular",
        "modifier": "log1p",
        "factor":   0.1
      },
      "boost_mode": "sum",
      "max_boost":  1.5
    }
  }
}
```

When I search a keyword like 'testa',the result only contains the keyword 'testa',What should I do to make the results contains keywords 'testa' and 'test' or 'tes'?
Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

You can use [ngram](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/analysis-ngram-tokenizer.html) for partial words search, but you need to reindex your documents.

You can check the [official example](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/analysis-ngram-tokenizer.html#_example_6)

Answer (score 0):

You may use [Fuzzy Match Query](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/guide/current/fuzzy-match-query.html) where your query will be like:

```
{
  "query": {
    "function_score": {
      "query": {
        "multi_match": {
          "query":    "testa",
          "analyzer":"standard",
          "fuzziness":"3",
          "type": "best_fields",
          "fields": [ "name^5", "content^1" ]
        }
      },
      "field_value_factor": {
        "field":    "popular",
        "modifier": "log1p",
        "factor":   0.1
      },
      "boost_mode": "sum",
      "max_boost":  1.5
    }
  }
}
```

Also, [Simple Query String Query](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/query-dsl-simple-query-string-query.html) might help but you will have to enter your term as "tes*", which may or may not be acceptable to your use case.